# Wordpress: when I click on a post, in a category, it loads the category, instead of the post content

Tags: wordpress, post, categories, posts

Here is a link to a site I am working on for a friend.

http://jayclarkephotography.com/category/wedding/

When I click on I click on "Wedding Test" or "Long's Wedding Gallery", it loads the category, not the post itself, I was messing around in the CSS and some of the PHP the other day and might have messed something up. I really need some help with this - I am not a web designer by any means but have a basic understanding of how it works.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: We need to know what your PHP looks like for that link, is it linking to `<?php the_permalink(); ?>` ?

Answer (score 1):

When you click on a post ("Wedding Test" or "Long's Wedding Gallery") it takes you to that post.

Wordpress by default when you add a post it creates a link after your website (for example http://YOURWEBSITE.com/YOUR-POST/) - If you want it to go to http://YOURWEBSITE.com/YOUR_CATEGORY/YOUR-POST/ you will have to set up [custom taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies)